# Not able to generate entities on JPA project with SQL server connection

Tags: jpa-2.1

When i tried to generate entities form tables on eclipse i see below error. I tried multiple java version as 9 and 10 also tried with different versions of jdbc jars but never got resolved.

**Below are the eclipse logs:**

!MESSAGE Error Generating Entities
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:109)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.init(Log4JLogChute.java:85)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.updateLog(LogManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLog(RuntimeInstance.java:728)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:240)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:534)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateClass(PackageGenerator.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateInternal(PackageGenerator.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.doGenerate(PackageGenerator.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generate(PackageGenerator.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.wizards.gen.GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard$GenerateEntitiesJob.runInWorkspace(GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at many solution. i tried to remove eclipse from my machine and have the new  download of eclipse version. This fixed the issue